# Distributing DCGAN with horovod on Sagemaker

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker, horovod

I am trying to distribute my workload to multiple GPUs with AWS Sagemaker. I am using a custom algorithm  for a DCGAN with tensorflow 2.0. The code thus far works perfect on a single GPU. I decided to implement the same code but with horovod distribution across multiple GPUs to reduce run time. The code, when changed from the original to horovod, seems to work the same, and the training time is roughly the same. However, when I print out hvd.size() I am only getting a  size of 1, regardless of the multiple GPU's present. Tensorflow recognizes all the present GPU's; Horovod, no.

I've tried running my code on both Sagemaker and on an EC2 instance in a docker container, and in both environments the same issue persists.

Here is the a link to my github repo:

[Here](https://github.com/nogya3z/sagemaker_dcgan_tf2.0/tree/distributed-gpu-dcgan/container)

I've also tried using a different neural network entirely from the horovod repository, updated to tf2.0:

[hvdmnist](https://github.com/horovod/horovod/blob/master/examples/tensorflow2_mnist.py)

At this point I am only trying to get the GPU's within one instance to be utilized, and am not trying utilize multiple instances.

I think I might be missing a dependency of some sort in the docker image, either that or there is some sort of prerequisite command for me to run. I don't really know.

Thanks.

Comment: To add, I want this to work for tensorflow 2.0. Sagemaker already has images designed for tensorflow but the latest release is tensorflow 1.15.

Comment: Amazon SageMaker now has support for TensorFlow 2.0.

Comment: @nogya3z Are you calling the training script using horovodrun? If you simply call the script with python, this is expected. Make sure you call the script using "horovodrun -np <num-gpus> python <training-script>".

Comment: @karakusc this did work! thank you. it recognizes the gpus now. I have some other issues now, but this solved the question asked.